# How do I depoy my Vue Express and Node SPA to Heroku so my Vue Router components will load?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a VueJS Node full stack application. The app works in when I run it locally but when I deploy it up to Heroku only my "/" page loads. The rest of the routes give a 404 Not Found message. Below is my Vue Router and Express files.

React Rounter:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Home.vue";
import { uriBase } from "../const";
import Services from "../components/Services.vue";
import MeetBrett from "../components/Brett.vue";



Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/Services",
    name: "Services",
  
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: Services
  },
  {
    path: "/meetBrett",
    name: "MeetBrett",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: MeetBrett
  },
  {
    path: "/quote",
    name: "Get Quote",
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/GetQuotePage.vue")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
   // base: '/dev', // for dev
  mode: "history",
  base: uriBase,
  routes
 

});

export default router;
```

**Node with Express** I use the connect-history-api-fallback

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-Parser");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const path = require('path');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

require('dotenv').config("./process.env")

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.set(port)

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());

// app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
// app.use(/.*/, (req, res) => express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.use(
  history({
    verbose: true,
    index: 'index.html'
  })
);

app.use(staticFileMiddleware);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Does you Vue app build into the Express `public` folder (as opposed to the default `dist`)?

Comment: It's unclear from your code but what is your base path for both dev and prod?

Comment: @Phil it builds into the Express public folder.

Comment: Ok, could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63679427/edit) to add the following... 1) When developing your front-end, what URL is open in your browser? It should be `http://localhost:88/dev` based on what you showed below. 2) How are you deploying to Heroku? Are you running `npm run build` for the Vue app before deploying? 3) What URL are you opening for the production app? You can obfuscate the hostname if you want

Comment: I run npm run build for the Vue App which builds to the Public folder on my backend. I then run npm start to run it locally. Here is the link on Heroku https://handymanslc.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use the `connect-history-api-fallback` middleware is to specify the absolute path to rewrite to. So where you have `index: 'index.html'`, it should be `index: '/index.html'`

This is the [default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback#index) though so you should probably just avoid overwriting it.

```js
app.use(history({
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
```

---

Some extra things for you to try out...

Set the base path for your front-end app in your `vue.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/'
    : '/dev/'
}
```

and reference this in your router

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions. changing connect-history-api-fallback to 'index: '/index.html'' and removing index and just doing

app.use(history({
  verbose: true
})

I still get the same error.


Any other Ideas?

Comment: Since you have `verbose` switched on, what does the logging say?

Comment: Rewriting GET / to /index.html
Not rewriting GET /css/app.08e5f594.css because the path includes a dot (.) character.


Rewriting GET /services to /index.html
Not rewriting GET /img/neonbrand-SiYxQRATT2M-unsplash.ddf4718e.jpg because the path in
Not rewriting GET /img/person-holding-pencil-1388944.88e59eae.jpg because the path inc

When deployed on Heroku on Google chrome it says 
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @WestonBell sounds like it's working fine. I've asked some questions above (in the questions comments). Could you please answer those?

Comment: I did both of the suggestions you mentioned earlier with no change. Here is what my vue.config.js looks like right now. 

`const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
      publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/'
    : '/dev/',
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Server/public"),
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      contentBase: "./public",
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      port: 88,
      historyApiFallback: true, // is it enabled ?
      inline: true,
    },
  },
};`

Comment: @WestonBell Not sure what you're doing with that `configureWebpack` bit but everything else works for me when I test it.

Comment: It works when run locally on localhost:5000 it only has an issue when I deploy it up to heroku.